# Flutter: Unable to connect package geolocation

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

> **I can not connect the package to pubspect.yaml geolocation**

```
 dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  geolocation: ^0.2.1
```

Appear an error:

[image: Sceenshot of problem]

```
[logining] flutter packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in logining...                   
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.

Because logining depends on geolocation >=0.1.1 which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1)
exit code 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: try using the https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location package.

Answer (score 0):

pub.dartlang.org prominently shows that this package is not compatible with Dart 2.

Flutter uses Dart 2 since about 5/2018, so you can't use this package with newer Flutter version.

[image]